# How do I get clientId of the client that made the request that triggered the Client filter?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I am writing an app in which I want to enrich an outgoing request based on some configuration.
Configuration example

```
clients:
  clientA:
    header1: value1
    header2: value2
  client2:
    header1: value3
    header2: value4
```

To do that I have two goals:

- Extend the native configuration to be able to add the more information
- In a ClientFilter, retrieve this information and add to the request

Talking about the second point:
1- Is there a way that I get the clientId of the client making the request on the filter? Or can I inject the client itself?
2- Is there a way for me to load the appropriate configuration based on the clientId?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "enrich an outgoing request"?  Depending on what you want to do, a filter may not be the only or best option.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown sorry for the delay. The idea is the following: my system makes http requests against other systems. Depending on the client, I should either use a token generated for my app or I should delegate the user's token for authentication on the target service. I want to use the filter to add the token to the outgoing request.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
There is a request attribute indicating that:

```
request.getAttribute("micronaut.http.serviceId")
```